# Splash Screen Animation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, splash-screen

I writing application for Android and want to make animated splash screen

I did image splash screen like this

Styles.xml:

```xml
 <resources>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And SplashActivity:

```cs
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Thread.Sleep(10000); 
        StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
    }
}
```

But I have 4 .png images and i want to make animated splash screen. How I can do this?

Comment: Try using Normal ImageView with Changing images after Certian Time using Timer and at Last start the Next Activity

Answer (score 0):

Use **Animation List** - create xml in your drawable folder like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="true">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="200" />

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="200" />

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="200" />

</animation-list>
```

Then start the animation like this:

```
ImageView your_imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
your_imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_animation_list);
AnimationDrawable your_animation = (AnimationDrawable) your_imageView.getBackground();

your_animation.start(); // Start the animation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FadeImageView class https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-fadeimageview/ to fade from one image to another with a delay

Include the FadeImageView as the tutorial and set the animations with something like this:

```
using Android.Views.Animations;

AlphaAnimation fadeIn;
AlphaAnimation fadeOut;

fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation (0, 1) {Duration = 500};
fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation (1, 0) {Duration = 500};
```

Then set what to happen when the animation ends like calling a method that changes the image

```
EventHandler<Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs> callback = (s, e) => {
    StartAnimation (fadeOut);
    ChangePic ();

};
fadeIn.AnimationEnd += callback;

fadeimageview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
fadeimageview.StartAnimation (fadeIn);
```

Something simple for ChangePic:

```
private void ChangePic(){
   if (bitmapList.Count >= 1)
   {
      fadeimageview.SetImageBitmap(bitmapList[bitmapList.Count - 1]);
      bitmapList.RemoveAt[bitmapList.Count - 1];
      fadeimageview.StartAnimation (fadeIn);
   }
}
```